# Splitting a comma separated string to a dictionary in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a string that looks like this:

```
s="Name1:Value1,Name2:Value2,Name3:Value3"
```

And I need to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
    "Name1": "Value1",
    "Name2": "Value2",
    "Name3": "Value3"
}
```

Which module or filter I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clean but you could try that:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - s: "Name1:Value1,Name2:Value2,Name3:Value3"
    - tuples: "[{% for sub in s.split(',') %}{{sub.split(':')}},{% endfor %}]"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(tuples) }}"
```

Which gives:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "Name1": "Value1",
        "Name2": "Value2",
        "Name3": "Value3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
set_fact:
    dict: "{{ dict|default({}) | combine ( { item.split(':')[0] : item.split(':')[1] } ) }}" 
  with_items: 
    - "{{ a.split(',') }}"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This gives an error: |combine expects dictionaries, got <function <lambda> at 0x7f9918d83668>

Comment: Nevermind :( I made a booboo. Make sure to replace both 'dict' variable names with your name otherwise you get the error I mentioned.